# Converting random xml file to tree diagram

Tags: xml, awk, tree, diagram

I am regularly running into cases where I need to convert XML files to tree diagram drawings. Could be a product catalog structure or a managed object model that I want to visualize.

Just wonder if someone can suggest a tool that takes XML (or some other text based input) and generates these kind of diagrams? I can of course convert my XML files with an awk (etc) script to pretty much any format, so it could be CSV input or pretty much anything text based.

Cheers!
Sam

Answer (score 4):

```
xmlstarlet el -u whatever.xml|awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{print "digraph{"}{print $(NF-1)" -> "$NF}END{print"}"}'|dot -Tpng -o xml.png

display xml.png
```

[image: image of xml structure]

**Hey!**
***it worked!***

I hope you work with smaller xml files than I do.

`xmlstarlet` parses xml, 
The `el` option displays the xml elements as simple xpath
the `-u` flag eliminates redundant sibling elements
there are other many options and refinements that would
for example include values or attributes.
The `awk` prints out the `dot` header,
then for each line in the file,
prints the last two elements of each xpath with a arrow separator
which corresponds to an edge between nodes in the ... err, nigh-DAG
in the `dot` format.
Notice, that without special handling this results in a self edge on any root node.
`awk` finally prints out the closing brace as a footer.

`dot`,
which is part of the GraphViz library,
reads the format `awk` has transformed the `xmlstarlet` output into
and is told to write out a png image
which may be viewed with anything

note: both graphviz/dot and xmlstarlet have a tons of options

The xml file used maybe found [here](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/clinvar/xml/sample_xml/RCV000077146.xml) (23 KB)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will test this one.

Comment: evolved a couple of bell and whistles here:     https://github.com/TomConlin/xpath2dot